# Unable to read SSHOperator output in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am having trouble understanding how to extract the output of `SSHOperator` in Airflow.

Here's my complete workflow:

```py
import base64
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator


@dag(
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 3, 1, tz="UTC"),
    tags=["test"],
)
def run_ssh():
    @task
    def ssh(remote_host):
        op = SSHOperator(task_id="ssh", remote_host=remote_host, command="ls -l")
        return op.output

    @task
    def read(value):
        # value = base64.b64decode(value).decode("utf-8")
        print("*********", value)

    read(ssh("myhost"))


run_ssh()
```

What gets printed in the task logs is:

```
********* {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='ssh', dag_id='adhoc_***', key='return_value') }}
```

The `SSHOperator` code seems to return the aggregated `stdout` (base64 encoded). Even when I turn on the base64 decode, it still seems to print the same templated value. What am I misunderstanding in this pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators inside of operators would not executed, because nor Airflow Scheduler nor Airflow worker doesn't know about it.

So when you call `op.output` it is just return Jinja template representation about task which never executed into the XCom.

```py
import base64
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator


@dag(
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 3, 1, tz="UTC"),
    tags=["test"],
)
def run_ssh():
    op = SSHOperator(task_id="ssh", remote_host="myhost", command="ls -l")

    @task
    def read(value):
        # value = base64.b64decode(value).decode("utf-8")
        print("*********", value)

    read(op.output)

run_ssh()
```

Comment: Excellent! I now realize that the Python functions themselves are operators. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, decorated by @task internally it is PythonOperator or could be other, but still internally it is operators